# Are individuals allowed to use accrual based accounting for federal income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Does the IRS allow individuals (not a business) to account for their income on an accrual basis rather than a cash basis for the purpose of paying personal Federal income taxes?

Note: This question is just a matter of curiosity and I'm not actually considering doing this.

Comment: See also [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/14040/5760) in which a comment claims that in India, only non-profit organizations are permitted to use cash basis; everyone else must use accrual basis. If true, weird....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. But once you chose the method (on your first tax return), you cannot change it without the IRS approval. Similarly the fiscal year.

For individuals, I can't think of any reason why would accrual basis be better than cash, or why would an individual use a fiscal year other than the calendar year.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source my understanding was that individuals couldn't use the accrual method?

Comment: @stoj couldn't? why couldn't? Its just too complicated and IMHO unjustified unless you have too high volume of transactions to track.